# $f$ is holomorphic in the unit circle, and for every $n \in \mathbb N$, $f( \frac {1}{n})=f( \frac {1}{n})^2$. Prove that $f=1$ or $f=0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

$f$ is holomorphic in the unit circle, and for every $n \in \mathbb N$, $f( \frac {1}{n})=f( \frac {1}{n})^2$. Prove that $f=1$ or $f=0$.

Any hints would be really great. Thanks!

Comment: Let $g(z) = f(z)\cdot (f(z)-1)$. Use the identity theorem.

Comment: Sadly I haven't studies this theorem yet. Any other way to solve this?

Comment: @Gareld Do you know that the zeros of a non-constant holomorphic function are isolated?

Comment: Not really. It basically is the identity theorem for a specific set.

Answer (score 0):

For all $n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}$ you have $f(\frac{1}{n}) \in \{0, 1\}$. Hence you have either $f(\frac{1}{\alpha_n})=0$ or $f(\frac{1}{\alpha_n})=1$ Where $(\alpha_n)$ is a sequence converging to $0$ of  different complexes.
Consequenquently $f= 0$ or $f=1$ according to the identity theorem for holomorphic functions.